# Increasing the size of the cell of with respect to the content coming from webservice in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

This may be a simple question but i wish to through the correct path.

Im fetching some contents from the webservice and displaying it in a table view.

The length of text that is fetching from there may vary.

Sometime it may have only one line sentence,sometime a paragraph etc.

So my doubt is how can i vary the height of custom cell according to the content coming from webservice.

Hoping for your help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: same question like this :-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443335/how-can-i-do-variable-height-table-cells-on-the-iphone-properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume you store the text for each content in an array. And the index lined up with the table cell.
Here is the code you want to use.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
NSString *string = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

//300 is the width, you can change this to make it look right.
CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(300 ,9999);
CGSize expectedLabelSize = [string sizeWithFont:YOURLABEL.font 
                                    constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize 
                                        lineBreakMode: UILineBreakModeWordWrap]; 

return expectedLabelSize.height;
```

}

Pretty much covers the basic. Just ask if you have any more questions. And read Leena's comment. It is pretty spot on.

Answer (score 0):

In you UITableViewDelegate implement the following method

`- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

returning the proper height according to the row.

you can use the method `-sizeWithFont:` of NSString to get the pixel size of the text you get.

http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/sizeWithFont:

Comment: but how to return with different heights with different text length