# iOS - Can I use xib file for variable height table cell where dynamic content and fixed content are mixed

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm creating a twitter-like app and I'm using a Table view for the feed. Each table cell is a custom cell. I'm designing those cells using xib file. The cell contains profile picture, comment count and a dynamic message block, etc. There are discussions around how to build variable height table cell: 
[How can I do variable height table cells on the iPhone properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443335/how-can-i-do-variable-height-table-cells-on-the-iphone-properly)

The question is, the dynamic content is in the middle of the cell. Below it is fixed height content. As far as I understand, xib file gives each element fixed X and Y value. Can I stack them together like what "div" would do in?

Answer (score 1):

In IB, in the file inspector (first tab of the left panel), disable "Use autolayout" (if you use a recent version of Xcode)
Then select the label which will have a different height (the proper twitter message) in the size inspector, in the size inspector, set the autosizing properly.
The 4 "things" around describe if the label will keep these dimensions fixed or no (in your case, select the 4) and the 2 arrows in the middle describe if the label will autoresize when its parentView is resized.
Then has rdelmar said, you need to implement the tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: method of the tableView delegate

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this is by using the  table view delegate method tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:. How you do it depends on what kind of content you're adding, but somehow, you need to calculate the size of the cell needed based on the data for each row, and return that number. The cell has to be designed in such a way, and with the proper layout constraints, so that when it expands, the part or UI element that you want to expand (like a text view or a multi-line label) expands properly.